# Mutiple ssh servers on a single IP - known_hosts complains

Tags: ssh

Given my default consumer-grade internet, I forwarded different ports
on my router to different servers, however, known_hosts complains
every time I log in. Can I tell it to distinguish by port?

```
Offending key for IP in $USER/.ssh/known_hosts:42
Matching host key in $USER/.ssh/known_hosts:50
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

Can I do this without disabling `CheckHostIP`?

Comment: dunno if relevant but you can configure ssh to listen on a few ports. on that line in sshd_config  says something like listen 22 or port 22 or something, you can add other ports there. or other lines that say listen xx or whatever. worth looking into perhaps

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/445253/how-to-edit-known-hosts-when-several-hosts-share-the-same-ip-and-dns-name

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked here:

[How to edit known_hosts when several hosts share the same IP and DNS name?](https://superuser.com/questions/445253/how-to-edit-known-hosts-when-several-hosts-share-the-same-ip-and-dns-name)

and the top answer references the a question here:

[How to handle ssh host key verification with 2 different hosts on the same (but changing) IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733753/how-to-handle-ssh-host-key-verification-with-2-different-hosts-on-the-same-but)

It more or less appears to be aliasing the different instances of SSH to keep them separate and ignoring the IP address.

Comment: Yeah, I already do the aliasing. But I don't like the `CheckHostIP` part.

Comment: I'd imagine you could ensure all servers have the same host key, but of-course that decreases your security.

Comment: @Tass: since you're port forwarding from your router (which I assume is on your local network), I fail to see how `CheckHostIP=no` would really decrease your security when you do have host key checks in place (which adds real security).

Comment: @eldering It does when I'm accessing the hosts from the internetz.