# Avoid SSH identity conflicts when dual booting on the same IP address

Tags: ssh, debian

I've got a home server that I dual boot with a Debian installation and a media center PC.

- I've setup an SSH server both.
- I've setup public key authentication to the Debian server based on IP
- When I start setting up the connection to the media center, SSH warns me that I might be under a man-in-the-middle attack, since a known IP suddenly provides a different identity.

I want to be able to connect to both the Debian installation and the media center, using different entries under `~/.ssh/config`. From the question [How to edit known_hosts when several hosts share the same IP and DNS name?](https://superuser.com/questions/445253/how-to-edit-known-hosts-when-several-hosts-share-the-same-ip-and-dns-name#comment1880208_445361), I realized I had two options:

1. Trick both installations "into having the same identity" by installing the same private keys on both computers
2. Trick my client into thinking both remote computers "are the same" by adding entries for both computers into `~/.ssh/known_hosts`

The answers address my question, but mix SSH setup for both servers. Is there a way that I can keep the configuration for each server separate, as separate entries under `~/.ssh/config`, where I can be explicit about which one I want to connect to, and avoid connecting to the wrong installation by accident? I'd accept solutions where I have to configure the network, since this is a learning experience for me.

Thanks!

Teodor

Comment: But.. why aren't you using the 3rd option mentioned in the question you linked? It sounds a lot like `HostKeyAlias` is precisely the option you want to be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key` files from one host to the other.

Another solution is to edit/create `~/.ssh/config` file and add 2 entries like:

```
Host debian
    HostName 192.168.1.10
    User mydebianuser
    HashKnownHosts ....
Host mediacenter
    HostName 192.168.1.10
    User mymediacenteruser
    HashKnownHosts ....
```