# SSH login on the same IP address but different OS?

Tags: ssh

I've connected Raspberry Pi with Raspbian OS to local network and set up the SSH login using ssh keys. I successfully log in just by `ssh myname@192.168.5.163` (assigned static IP to Raspberry Pi).

I have now removed the Raspbian OS, and inserted an SD card with Ubuntu Server (headless) on it.

I turned on the Raspberry Pi and tried to login, but I got error:

```
ERROR: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
ERROR: @    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
ERROR: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
ERROR: IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
ERROR: Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
ERROR: It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
ERROR: The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
ERROR: SHA256:asfasfdasdfasfdasfdasdfasdfasdfasdfasfasdf.
ERROR: Please contact your system administrator.
ERROR: Add correct host key in /home/joedoe/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
ERROR: Offending ECDSA key in /home/joedoe/.ssh/known_hosts:13
ERROR:   remove with:
ERROR:   ssh-keygen -f "/home/joedoe/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "192.168.5.163"
ERROR: ECDSA host key for 192.168.5.163 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
ERROR: Host key verification failed.
```

I went on and added to my `.ssh/config`:

```
host 192.168.5.163
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

but now I get

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/joedoe/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /home/joedoe/.ssh/known_hosts:13
  remove with:
  ssh-keygen -f "/home/joedoe/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "192.168.5.163"
Password authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
Keyboard-interactive authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
ubuntu@192.168.5.163: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Clearly the problem is that I want to log in into two different OSes on the same IP address, but the new Ubuntu OS does not wave the SSH login setup, and it doesn't allow me to log in in any way.

How should I proceed in order to be able to use both OSes interchangeably?

Comment: This is very much by design.  It is telling you that the system you think you are talking to, is not that system anymore (even though it is the same hardware).  For most situations other than yours this is very much something you'd like to know.

Comment: `SHA256:asfasfdasdfasfdasfdasdfasdfasdfasdfasfasdf` - Haha, I love that you care about security little enough to disable strict host key checking (which is bad), and yet you go through the trouble to censor a public key fingerprint (which shouldn't matter) :)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/445253/how-to-edit-known-hosts-when-several-hosts-share-the-same-ip-and-dns-name

Comment: "but the new Ubuntu OS does not wave the SSH login setup" Clearly it has, but with a different key. The message even tells you how to proceed.

Comment: does the message not tell you how to remove the old key?

Comment: @user253751 It does, but I wasn't sure about the consequences of that step.

Comment: Almost the same question with multiple solutions: [How to edit known_hosts when several hosts share the same IP and DNS name?](https://superuser.com/q/445253/61370) --- I would use a different IP address for each OS if possible.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are several potential solutions.

The easiest solution is the one davidgo proposed in his answer, which, as he mentions, leaves you open to a MitM attack (unlikely, but it's good to practice good security even in private situations).

```
  Host 192.168.5.163
      StrictHostKeyChecking no
      UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

A slightly better solution would be, as Eugen Rieck proposed, to synchronize the `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_*key*` files between both target OS systems.

A more reliable method would be to specifically decide which OS to connect to, so you do get an error if you connect to the wrong OS. That would for example allow scripts using ssh to fail if they target the wrong OS.
You can do that by using effectively an Alias in the `~/.ssh/ssh_config`.

```
Host raspbian-pi
  Hostname 192.168.5.163
  UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts_raspbian

Host centos-pi
  Hostname 192.168.5.163
  UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts_centos
```

You can then connect with `ssh <your_user>@raspbian-pi` to retrieve the Raspbian OS key, then switch to CentOS on your Raspberry Pi, do the same with `ssh <your_user>@centos-pi` to get the CentOS key. Then, in the future, whenever you connect to the wrong OS, you will get the host key error. Make sure to use the correct OS the first time you use the SSH command, so you don't accidentally store the CentOS host key in the Raspbian known hosts file.

Disclaimer: I've never used this solution and I'm not in a position to test it, but it should work correctly from my understanding and the documentation of ssh.

Comment: Yhis answer is  very under-rated (wish I could upvote it more).  Maybe if you focussed more on your approach and less on other peoples you would get more credit?

Comment: The first part of this answer is not a good fix. It bypasses key checking entirely, defeating the security of ssh. The second part is much more reasonable and should be the first or only answer.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: To be slightly fair, SSH without host-key checking still defends against passive attacks, requiring active MITM to read the traffic.  That might be somewhat harder for some attackers, otherwise you'd just use `rsh` with purely IP-based authentication instead of `ssh` for faster logins without doing any extra round-trips or crypto before starting a shell.  (Like you might do on the private internal side of an HPC cluster where the traffic only goes over hard-wired ethernet within one rack or machine room, not wifi)

Comment: Instead of `UserKnownHostsFile ...`, `HostKeyAlias raspbian-pi-hostkey` and `HostKeyAlias centos-pi-hostkey` would also work.

Answer (score 30):

You can fix the immediate problem by following the instruction in the error (you must do this each time you switch boxes) -

```
ssh-keygen -f "/home/joedoe/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "192.168.5.163"
```

The problem you are running into is that your computer has detected that the system its logging into is different to the one previously seen, and the warning is there to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks.

There are a number of ways of dealing with this properly. They include:

1. Setting up names for each box in `/etc/hosts` and then referring to the SSH connection by name rather than IP.  In this way SSH will associate different server fingerprints with each name.
2. Ignoring the check (this opens you up to mitm attacks so only do it if you understand and are comfortable with the risks.)  You can ignore this check with by adding `-o  UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` to your ssh command or `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`

   2a. You can create a config that only ignores the key check for the one IP by putting the following into `~/.ssh/config`

   Host 192.168.5.163
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
   UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
3. I wouldn't advise it unless the machines fill the same role, but you could make the host keys in `/etc/ssh` the same on both  servers (and `restart sshd` on the one you changed). In this way both servers will appear the same to the client.

Comment: What I did was `ssh-keygen -f "/home/joedoe/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "192.168.5.163"` and then I just copied the key: `ssh-copy-id ubuntu@192.168.5.163`. Now Ubuntu works, but I haven't checked the 1st Raspbian OS.

Comment: The ssh-keygen command above deleted the memory of the remote systems id from your pc (by removing its public key from your known_hosts file.  ssh-copy-id wont do anything here as that is your user key.  You need to sync the raspian and ubuntu server key which is on the ubunto/raspian machine in its /etc directory.  You need to copy the files manually if you want the systems to work interchangeably.

Comment: The 1st proposition has more info at [Connect to Linux by name rather than IP](https://superuser.com/questions/185678/connect-to-linux-by-name-rather-than-ip).

Answer (score 21):

The easiest way to do this ist to copy `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key*` from one installation to the other - this will give both OSes the same host keys and thus the fingerprint.

Comment: Because this answer is a specific solution that is technically not a great implementation of security. If you want multiple systems to login to the same system, authenticate the two systems separately so you know which one is which, instead of having the two share the same key.

Comment: How do I copy files if I can't login.

Comment: @akostadinov - I didn't actually miss it, I referred to it (albeit more obliquely) in option 3

Comment: @Danijel there are multiple ways, including using the ssh-keygen -f ... command when you switch between the systems.   So copy them from 1 system to your PC, then run ssh-keygen -f..., then copy them from your PC to the new system, then restart ssh on the remote system and run ssh-keygetn -f... one last time.

Comment: Tried it, works. This gives me just what I asked for: to switch two SD cards on my Raspberry Pi board, therefore switching between two different OSes, and have the same login credentials at the same time.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to give each OS a different IP address.  They get the same one now because the DHCP server sees the same MAC address.  So you could configure one install to use a static IP address.

I would follow Eugen's suggestion though - that simplifies things.  Or get a second Pi and run both machines at once.

Comment: You could also probably force the MAC address to be different for each OS.

Comment: This is actually sound, and some ISP routers seem to take the hint if the hostname has changed.   Be aware you may need to reserve both addresses in DHCP anyway to prevent duplicates. You could also use differing NICs. especially if you use USB dongles from a Zero say?

Answer (score 0):

I personally use an OpenSSH Certificate Authority for all my Linux servers. This saves a lot of hassle when setting up a new one and orchestrating my terminal devices (desktops, laptops and jump hosts), which I previously [blogged about](https://ibug.io/p/30).

While this feature isn't originally designed for this (unusual) use case, it provides an alternative solution to the problem. Just sign both host keys with the private key of your CA and add the public part to your `known_hosts` file, and your SSH client will automatically trust both sets of host keys without yelling at you about the discrepancies. You may still need to remove any remembered host keys with `ssh-keygen -R` beforehand, though.

This has the advantage that both systems can keep their host keys separated and different, which provides you with the ability to distinguish them by host keys (and certificates - there's an "identity" field that you can customize when signing the certificates). This is also secure in that you don't have to blindly trust an arbitrary host that shows up at that specific IP address.

Even if you want to protect yourself against leaked keys, you can add "allowed names / IP addresses" as "principals" when signing the certificates, for example:

```
ssh-keygen -s my_ca -I "RaspOS on RPi" -h -n 192.0.2.0 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

The certificate will *not* be trusted unless presented from the host at `192.0.2.0`, unless an attacker somehow hijacks your traffic *in addition to* the host keys and certificates.

---

Well, now I have to admit it's easier to copy the host keys between both OS's since they're on the same physical machine after all.